# How to reverse a parallel array in Data Parallel Haskell

Tags: arrays, haskell, parallel-processing

Is there a way to reverse a parallel array in Data Parallel Haskell? The GHC.PArr module seems to export a method called reverseP but I get an error when trying to use it.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: DPH is experimental. You might consider using Repa. http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell:_A_Repa_Tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what sort of error you get, I can't tell you how to fix it.

However, you could convert your parallel array to a list and then back:

```
reverseP' = toP.reverse.fromP
```